# Open Graph tags not recognized by iMessage

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, imessage

I'm trying to add an og:title tag to a page. It works fine when testing it on Facebook/Slack, and the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) shows all the data I would expect. Do I need to do anything extra to get these tags to work on iOS that isn't necessary for Facebook/Slack?

Thanks!

Edit:
Here is the content of the raw tags that the Facebook debugger can see:

```
<meta xmlns:fb="http://developers.facebook.com/schema/" property="fb:app_id" content="[My App ID]" />
<meta xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" property="og:title" content="My Title" />
<meta xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" property="og:image" content="[My Image URL]" />
<meta xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" property="og:description" content="This is My Description" />
<meta xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" property="og:site_name" content="My Site Name" />
<meta xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" property="og:url" content="[My URL]" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="My Title" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="[My Image URL]" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="My Description" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
```

Comment: Do you have an og:image as well, or just an og:title? I'd guess it might need the pair: [TN2444](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2444/_index.html) shows both. (You also might want to say iMessage in the title rather than iOS - it took me a bit to realise what you were talking about, and only then did I notice the tag.)

Comment: Hey Rup, sorry I forgot to mention an image tag already exists and works on all platforms. I've updated the question with the tags seen by the Facebook debugger.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that iMessage will use schema.org markup on a page instead of `og:image` when it's compiling a preview image. So for a product page for example, if you have recommended complementary products on the same page, you may get an image comprised of those recommended products instead of the main product on the page. (If you don't have schema.org markup on the product's images as well.)

I can't find any documentation to support this behavior, but I've seen it first hand.